# Javascript function, calls another function, but return false doesn't stop

Tags: javascript, function

When I run this code it doesn't seem to be doing what I expect.  So this is a validation, and when I run the if statement, the validator stops running when it hits the false. But when it hits the false from the other function numCheck, it alerts but then just continues. Since there are more validations below, if the numCheck comes back clean, how do I continue through the rest of the validation rather than cutting out if it's true? Where am I going wrong?

```js
function numCheck(num){
 if(isNaN(num)){
  alert("Vendor number must be numeric");
  focusTo(document.forms["parts"]["vendorNo"]);
  return false;
 }
}

function validateForm(){
//DECLARATION
 var vendorNo = document.forms["parts"]["vendorNo"].value;
//VENDOR NUMBER
  numCheck(vendorNo);
 if(vendorNo.length != 4){
  alert("Please enter 4 digit Vendor Number");
  focusTo(document.forms["parts"]["vendorNo"]);
  return false;
 }
```

Thank you in advance, I've spent a lot of time trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

**You must also return from the parent (calling) function, validateForm**

Your subroutine numCheck will return back to the calling function validateForm

```js
function numCheck(num){
 if(isNaN(num)){
  alert("Vendor number must be numeric");
  focusTo(document.forms["parts"]["vendorNo"]);
  return false;
 }
return true;
}

function validateForm(){
//DECLARATION
 var vendorNo = document.forms["parts"]["vendorNo"].value;
//VENDOR NUMBER
  if (numCheck(vendorNo)==false){
     console.log("Invalid vendorNumber");
     return; // you must also return from the calling function, otherwise the code will still continue.
  }
 if(vendorNo.length != 4){
  alert("Please enter 4 digit Vendor Number");
  focusTo(document.forms["parts"]["vendorNo"]);
  return false;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

returning from `numCheck` does not mean `validateForm` has returned anything. Check the return value of `numCheck` and then take the appropriate action.

```
function validateForm(){
  ...
  // numCheck returns a boolean here. If it returns false, return from this function
  if(!numCheck(vendorNo)) {
    return false;
  }
 ....
```